# What is the location of the Geany preferences/settings files?

Tags: geany

I've made quite a few changes to the preferences for my convenience. Now, I want to install it on several computers with the modified preferences. 
It would be far easier if I can just copy the preferences/settings file(s) from the modified installation into the new installation folders instead of modifying the preferences of each new installation one by one. 
Where am I to find the preferences/settings files of Geany?

Comment: some error can solve by doing :`cd ~/.config/geany` and `sudo chown user *`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run in your terminal

```
locate geany.conf
```

This is the file where your preferences are being stored. For shortcuts, search for `keybindings.conf`.

Comment: Not everyone has `locate` (`mlocate`) enabled and running.

Comment: And not everyone runs Geany under linux.

Answer (score 7):

If you are running Geany on Linux/BSD you will find them in folder *~/.config/geany*

On very ancient versions of Geany there have been a *~/.geany* folder.

As for deploying it on other computers: Keep care, as inside file *geany.conf* there are absolute paths defined, which are e.g. dependent on your username.

Comment: Watch out, the `~/.config/geany/geany.conf`is created after the first run of `geany`, after installing the program there's no such file.

Comment: BTW, any idea of where is the plugins configuration stored? (e.g. 'save when loosing focus' is active in my installation, what is the file that keeps this value?

Comment: OK, pretty obvious: `~/.config/geany/plugins`

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Geany manual](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#configuration-file-paths), you can check the paths Geany is using with menu *Help* → *Debug Messages*. Near the top there should be two lines with something like:

```
Geany-INFO: System data dir: /usr/share/geany
Geany-INFO: User config dir: /home/username/.config/geany
```

### Paths on Unix-like systems

The system path is `$prefix/share/geany`, where `$prefix` is the path where Geany is installed (see Installation prefix).
The user configuration directory is normally: `/home/username/.config/geany`

### Paths on Windows

The system path is the `data` subfolder of the installation path on Windows.

The user configuration directory might vary, but on Windows XP it's: `C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\Application Data\geany`. On Windows 7 and above you most likely will find it at: `C:\users\UserName\Roaming\geany`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find it is menu *Tools* → *Configuration Files* → *snippets.conf*.

It will open a new tab. In the **title bar** there will be the path where **geany.conf resides**.

In my particular case it was:

```
~/.var/app/org.geany.Geany/config/geany
```